# Slick No matching Shape found

Tags: scala, slick

```
  case class Supplier(id:Int,name:String,street:String,city:String,state: String,zip:String)

  class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Supplier](tag,"Suppliers") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey)// This is the primary key column
    def name = column[String]("Name")
    def street = column[String]("Street")
    def city = column[String]("City")
    def state = column[String]("State")
    def zip = column[String]("Zip")

    override def * = (id,name, street, city, state, zip) <> ((Supplier.apply _).tupled, Supplier.unapply)
  }
  val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]

  case  class Coffee(name:String, supID:Int, price:Double, sales:Int, total:Int)

  class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[Coffee](tag, "Coffees") {
    def name = column[String]("Name", O.PrimaryKey)
    def supID = column[Int]("Sup_ID")
    def price = column[Double]("Price")
    def sales = column[Int]("Sales")
    def total = column[Int]("Total")
    def * = (name, supID, price,sales,total) <> ((Coffee.apply _).tupled, Coffee.unapply)

    def supplier = foreignKey("Sup_FK", supID, suppliers)(_.id)
  }
  val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
```

these are table definitions and I want to do a join query

```
val manualJoin = for {
    c <- coffees if c.price < 9.0
    s <- suppliers if s.id===c.supID
  } yield (c.name,s.name)
```

but it gives bellow error

```
No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection,
 you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List),
 or you forgot to import a driver api into scope.
  Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
     Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[String], slick.lifted.Rep[String])
   Unpacked type: T
     Packed type: G

    s <- suppliers if s.id===c.supID
```

I don't understand how to resolve this.can someone please explain what's the problem is?

These are the imports

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import slick.ast.ScalaBaseType.stringType
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
```

Comment: Can you show the imports you've used too. That'll be helpful to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `import slick.ast.ScalaBaseType.stringType` line. I suspect this is introducing an ambiguous implicits into scope.

Comment: It worked!!! I removed that import and then I got the results without the error.Thank you so much.